Are objects in different categories associated with the same set identical?
Take $S=\{\mathbb{Q},\times,+\}$. Do you think that, according to the average mathematician (if she has an opinion on this question) the copy of $S$ that lives in $Ring$ is the same object as the copy of $S$ that lives in $Field$? It occurs to me that one might think either
(i) Neither the object in $Ring$ (call it $\mathbb{Q}_{Ring}$) nor the object in $Field$ (call it $\mathbb{Q}_{Field}$) are identical to $S$.
or perhaps instead
(ii) $\mathbb{Q}_{Ring}$ and $\mathbb{Q}_{Field}$ are identical to $S$ and therefore identical to each other.
This is admittedly a somewhat odd question, because the rationals form a field and one typically doesn't care per se about ring structure of the rationals. Nevertheless, your opinions are most welcome. Thank you in advance.

But being a field is not a different structure, it's a property.

Most mathematicians would regard them as the same object, i.e. the ring $\mathbb{Q}$ is the same thing as the field $\mathbb{Q}$.
Formally, a ring or a field is defined as a tuple $(R,+,\cdot,0,1)$ (perhaps omitting the $0$ or $1$ up to preference) that just meets a set of properties. The list of properties for a field is simply more restrictive than those for a ring. Namely, for a ring:

$(R,+)$ is an abelian group
$(R,\cdot)$ is a semigroup
Distribution is satisfied on both sides
Some will additionally assume $R$ has a multiplicative identity $1$ (a unital ring)

But for a field, you will need all of the above, and:

$(R\setminus\{0\},\cdot)$ is an abelian group
$0 \ne 1$

The exact same type of object can satisfy any of the $6$ bullets, or all of them: those $5$-tuples $(R,+,\cdot,0,1)$. The properties simply mean that those satisfying all six are a subcollection of those satisfying the first four.

To add to this in terms of categories/"collections": $\mathrm{Field}$ is a full subcategory of $\mathrm{Ring}$, i.e. all fields are rings and a field homomorphism is the same as a ring homomorphism with co/domain a field. From this point of view, you might as well ask whether the empty set in $\mathrm{FinSet}$ and the one in $\mathrm{Set}$ are the same object, which I'm sure at least 99/100 mathematicians will answer with "yes, of course" without any hesitation :)
